# Can I enable autosave on non-realistic save setting?

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

I recently have started a new realistic game of Warband as on my non-realistic one there was no autosave once I visited a town or made camp. Which let me lose progress a lot of times as I forgot to save quite frequently.

On realistic, it saves all the time yet it is kind of a bit too much rogue-like gameplay for my taste. I really did like the option to "cheat" by reloading.

So I was wondering: Is there a an option to enable autosave on non-realistic game setting?

Comment: But doesn't the non-realistic have the options to save and quit? :p

Answer (score 1):

According to [this thread](http://forums.taleworlds.com/index.php?topic=88854.0)  the game autosaves no matter what setting you are in, but you won't be able to see the saves usually unless you are playing realistic mode.

Here is the relevant quote:

> It doesn't matter what save setting you have, the game still autosaves. If you're not using realistic save settings the autosaves still happen, you just won't see them in game.
>   You'll find them here:
>   C:\Users\YOUR USER NAME\Documents\Mount&Blade Savegames\Native
>   Rename them to the name of your normal save and replace it, then load the game, it'll load the autosave.

If that is too much of a hassle, you can always remember to use the quicksave feature more often.  The default key for that is F12.